# How to calculate face elements using Tango Mesh

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, google-project-tango

I want to export mesh using Tango API to a obj file.

Basics : OBJ file needs vertices (v) , vertex normal (vn), textures(if existed) (vt) , faces (f).

From what i have understood, i was successfull to derive vertices and vertex normal . A point cloud raw image can be seen accurately in PCL Viewer or Blender which is great .

Im not able to figure out how to calculate surface.
Hence, the raw image is plotting only the point cloud data as told earlier which is fine , but surfaces are the main factor in my situation.

I have understood the format for an obj file , currently following is my format :

```
v x y z
.
.
.
vn x y z
.
.
.
```

Now i need to include the face element

```
f v1//vn1 v2//vn2 v3//vn3
```

Question is how to calculate that "f" w.r.t vertices and vertex normal ?

I have also observed some examples , that deals with some vector cross product .

Someone make my concepts clear ?

Any article that explains how to calculate it ? or probably a pseudocode to get me started ?

Please ask if any logical code required i'll post it right away.